# Customizing slider in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have experienced some trouble with the Slider control on WP7. When I am dragging it, it will only drag a little bit, and then it goes back to where it started. If I let go of the slider quickly, then it goes a little further. E.g. if you want to drag it from the start to the end, you will have to quickly drag many times. What I want is a smooth slider, which follows my finger and stops until I release my finger, and it should stop where my finger is. Any way to get this the way I want?

I am also having a bit of trouble customizing it visually. How can I resize it and put it in the middle of the parent controller? Now, it puts itself in the top section, even though Vertical option is set to bottom..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue. The problem was that you can not(for some odd reason) have a slider and a gesturelistener at the same page. I removed the gesturelistener and the slider was smooth. I will not call that bad programming skills, this is definitely a bug, because the gesturelistener was on a totally different control in the page.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know where your finger are? Your finger is obviously going to be larger than the Slider itself.

The default slider is perfectly smooth. So all you're complaining about is the level of precision. You won't get 100% precision with a touch-interface that depends on the calibration of touch-input on your touch-screen.

Either you make the slider go in steps (which isn't smooth), or you accept the lower level of precision.

Comment: If it is like you are saying, then it seems like my slider is going in steps. How can this eventually be turned off? I accept the lower level of precision, but it should be smooth when sliding, and when I put in a default one, it is not. Weird, but true in my case ;)

Comment: It's smooth here. Get a real device, or a proper PC that can handle running the emulator.

Comment: I have a real device, so that´s not the problem. I am trying to fix this problem, and suddenly I noticed something very strange. The slider I want to fix is in page2.xaml.This slider has the "bug" as explained earlier.But,I tried adding another slider in page1.xaml, and that one behaved correctly.Now,if I go back to page1 and slide around, it works perfectly. Then, I go to page2 and the slider is still behaving wrong. And then, when I go back to page 1(the one that worked) this slider will behave exactly as stupid as the one on page2. Could it have something to do with what container it is in?

Comment: I am also using MVVM, could this be the problem? The one slider that worked did not use MVVM... And the page is not a panorama or a pivot!